# Javascript fetch return true and call not returning result

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am using the fetch library and I am trying this:

```
fetchtest() {
    fetch('someurl...').then((data) => {
        if (data.status === 200) {
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

then to call it:

```
myMethod() {
    if (this.fetchtest()) {
        console.info('Would return true');
    }
}
```

It's not returning anything.

What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It returns a promise so it may be not present at the time it is needed to be used.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `this.fetchtest()` is returning a Promise which is 'truthy' in nature.